# Finding a value from the previous row in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
Date             UUID         Value         RANK
01/03/2019        A            0              2
28/02/2019        A            1              1
28/02/2019        B            2              2 
26/02/2019        B            3              1
24/02/2019        C            4              2
21/02/2019        C            1              1
```

And I want to get the following:

```
Date             UUID         Value         RANK     PreValue
01/03/2019        A            0              2       1
28/02/2019        A            1              1       N/A
28/02/2019        B            2              2       3
26/02/2019        B            3              1       N/A
24/02/2019        C            4              2       1
21/02/2019        C            1              1       N/A
```

How would I go about getting the previous value?

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: So effectively what I want to do is shift the value based on the rank and uuid

Comment: If you are shifting the rank, why do I see a 3 in PreValue? There's no 3 in the rank column.

Comment: @coldspeed its shifting `Value`

Comment: Apologies removed that part of the question as I realised it will cause an issue. I've ordered the the dataframe by the Rank and I need to get the value from the previous rank. So in regards to your question, for B, where rank=1 the value is 3, so the previous value is 3 where rank=2 for  B

Comment: You need to add more columns. Time would go from left to right (old --> new). When you're done you might want to swap the column order to get (new --> old) for readability to the "past".

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there, just missing the `.groupby`:

```
df['PrevValue'] = df.sort_values(['UUID', 'RANK']).groupby('UUID').Value.shift(1)

print(df)
         Date UUID  Value  RANK  PrevValue
0  01/03/2019    A      0     2        1.0
1  28/02/2019    A      1     1        NaN
2  28/02/2019    B      2     2        3.0
3  26/02/2019    B      3     1        NaN
4  24/02/2019    C      4     2        1.0
5  21/02/2019    C      1     1        NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

A fun way , using `idxmax` with `drop`, the just `shift` whole Value and condition assign

```
df.loc[df.index.drop(df.groupby('UUID').RANK.idxmin()),'New']=df.Value.shift(-1)
df
         Date UUID  Value  RANK  New
0  01/03/2019    A      0     2  1.0
1  28/02/2019    A      1     1  NaN
2  28/02/2019    B      2     2  3.0
3  26/02/2019    B      3     1  NaN
4  24/02/2019    C      4     2  1.0
5  21/02/2019    C      1     1  NaN
```